# Was it possible for God to be a single person like in Islam and Judaism? Or is the attribute of "Trinity" an essential property of God?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, persons-of-the-trinity

Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that the Father "begot" the son from eternity. I suppose you could formulate my question as, *did the Father have any choice in this?* As in, could he have chosen **not** to beget the son, thus remaining a unity of persons rather than "becoming" a Trinity of persons?

Or is the Trinity of persons considered an essential property of God such that it simply couldn't have been any other way?

(I know that in one sense, the Trinity IS an essential property of God, because all of God's properties are essential. So I'm finding it hard to formulate my question accurately, but I hope you get the gist of what I'm asking)

I'm interested in answers from any "Critical scholars" as per Dick Harfield's comment

Comment: For this question to work here, you'll need to specify a group or denomination of Christians whose answer you are interested in.

Comment: As stated by Lee, you can nominate a particular denomination (eg Catholic or Lutheran) whose view is important to you, or you can ask for a position held by critical scholars. As it stands, the question is too broad for this site.

Comment: While I'm sure many people have entertained the question, I don't think this is a particularly fruitful kind of speculation. Whether or not 'choice' is an appropriate category, the difference suggested is so significant that the God in question could not be seen as being in any way the same as the God that is. And even if 'choice' is allowed, the inability for God to act contrary to his nature might negate that choice. So sorry, but I have voted to close as too philosophical.

Comment: Vote to reopen per the inclusion of Dick's suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure that "critical scholars" is a meaningful group in this case, as their views on the doctrine of God will vary significantly.

Comment: @Nathaniel OK, then why not have a one line answer, with God all things are possible.  At least that's covered in non controversial scripture. (I am aware that we prefer long answers).

Comment: (I'd like to propose an answer, but question is on hold) I think your main problem is that you fail to handle the difference of nature of God vs human creatures. God doesn't "make decisions" or "decide to change" like us in our human, temporal framework. God is eternal and ever-existing without change. He just IS. So He IS one-and-trine and didn't "decide to be a trinity / have a son" (human thinking). The Son is as eternal and ever-existing as the father. The fact that the Father "begot" the son is not to be interpreted in our human, "father/son" framework but in a "Godly" way. (...)

Comment: Vote to reopen, and I don't think it requires limitation to a particular Christian denomination. 

In every Christin denomination, God is love. Love is essential to God's nature. But love requires two persons, a lover and a beloved. Because Christianity teaches that God IS love, then a unitarian concept is illogical. Further, if God's nature is the basis for morality, He must exist at minimum as a trinity; morality requires how to relate to oneself, to another, and then to a third person; (I, we, they). This requires at least three persons.